# How to get the file creation date of a file?

Tags: file, axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, x++

How to get the creation date of a PDF file in Microsoft Dynamics AX 2009 with X++?

And how to open that PDF file in the button click?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no build in function to do that, but you could ask Windows.

The WinAPi [getFileTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724320%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function returns a [filetime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724290%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure. However both the parameters and the return value is a little difficult to interface to (look at other function in the AX WinAPI class).

Much easier is the interface to the .Net [getCreationTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.getcreationtime.aspx) method (do be defined in WinAPI):

```
client static UTCDateTime getFileCreationTime(str name)
{
    return CLRSystemDateTime2UtcDateTime(System.IO.File::GetCreationTime(name));
}
```

To be used like:

```
static void Job1(Args _args)
{;
    info(strFmt("%1", WinAPi::getFileCreationTime(@"C:\Users\zjbk\My Documents\ActionTool_SysFlushDictionaryServer.xpo")));
}
```

To open a PDF or whatever file using the default viewer:

```
WinAPI::ShellExecute(@"C:\test.pdf");
```